# Can't read a word from an old document

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not entirely sure if this is the right place to ask this, but going through some old documents from my great grandfather I discovered a line with a word which I don't understand, the word was "and _______ from house to house" - I've included a shot of the original document and a zoom of the line in question below, I originally thought it may have been 'Saunter', but it doesn't quite look like it.

If anybody can do a better job of deciphering this than me I'd really appreciate the help.

[image: Original Image]

[image: Zoomed Version]

Comment: it says " and journeyed from"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because deciphering handwriting is not really a question of English Language and Usage (bad writing can arise in any language).

Comment: (I also agree it is meant to be "journeyed", although it looks like the cursive is a bit sloppy and actually spells out "jounajed".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to say, **"and journeyed from house to house...."** Best of luck deciphering the rest of the letter. For me, it was pretty rough going.